# Python 'Integer devide by Zero' error Pyglet and AVBin

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyglet

I am currently running python 2.7 and am attempting to install Pyglet module with AVBin. It seems to be working fine for graphics and other things that do not require AVBin but everything else has errors.

This the error that i am recieving.

---

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 6.1.7601]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Python>media.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Python\media.py", line 3, in <module>
sound = pyglet.media.load('music.mp3')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1406, in l
oad
source = get_source_loader().load(filename, file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1382, in l
oad
return avbin.AVbinSource(filename, file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\avbin.py", line 268, in __ini
t__
av.avbin_stream_info(self._file, i, info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\avbin.py", line 198, in f
result = func(*args)
WindowsError: exception: integer divide by zero
```

---

The python script file has been executed from a windows command prompt. I am new to Python and so have limited knowledge of it's workings. I am running 64bit windows 7 with 64bit beta version of pyglet and 64bit version of AVBin.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was probably cause by [this bug](https://github.com/AVbin/AVbin/issues/49) that was fixed in [AVbin 11 alpha 4](https://github.com/AVbin/AVbin/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the AVBin module is clashing with the Pyglet module and attempting to divide by zero.

The only way I can think of solving this is by using something other than AVBin to install

Comment: Thanks for you reply. AVBin is an external library however which is used by pyglet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Without seeing any code it's hard to give much advice.